# nestjs swagger get request. how to add the search,sort parameter?

Tags: javascript, swagger, nestjs

i have a request:

```
@Get('getClients1')
  
  async getClients1(@Req() req:Request) {
   const s=req.query.s;
    const builder = await this.service.queryBuilder('user');
    if (s) {
      builder.where(
        'user.name LIKE :s OR user.surname LIKE :s',
        { s: `%${s}%` },
      );
    }
    const clients = await builder.getMany();
    return {
        data: users,
       
    };
```

he works. I'm trying to run it through a swager, it doesn't work.

I add:

```
@ApiParam({
    name: 'search',
    required: false,
    description: 'Строка для поиска по текстовым полям модели по ilike %search% \n (name,surname,patronymic,typeEducation)',
    type: String
  })
 and @param
@Get('getClients1')
  async getClients1(@Param('search') s: string)
```

but nothing comes.
[enter image description here][1]

why is the parameter not passed? and how can this be fixed?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEzCd.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `@ApiQuery()` not `@ApiParam()`. It's the difference of a query parameter (`someUrl/?q=some+search+thing`) vs a url parameter (`someUrl/url/parameters`). Also, use `@Query()` instead of `@Param()`